# Failed code to compute the difference of Summer and Winter Gold Medals relative to the total Gold Medals

Tags: python

I am trying to write a function that find s the difference between the Summer Gold Medals and Winter Gold Medals relative to the total number of Gold Medals, which is in effect the sum of the two, for a CSV file which I have represented in a table format using DataFrame. I have writen what I think is a correct code, following an alogorithm, but it doesnt seem to work.

```
def myFunction(dfNew):
quotient = 0
for col in dfNew.columns:
    if col[:3] == 'Gold':
        if col[:3] == 'Gold.1':
            if dfNew[(dfNew['Gold'] > 0) & (dfNew['Gold.1'] >= 0)]:
                summerGold = dfNew.loc[:,['Gold']]
                winterGold = dfNew.loc[:,['Gold.1']]
                diffOfGold = summerGold - winterGold
                sumOfGold = summerGold + winterGold
                quotient = diffOfGold / sumOfGold
            return quotient;
```

The above code produces the error message

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-59-026b8477f2e0> in <module>
----> 1 quotient

NameError: name 'quotient' is not defined
```

Pls what am I doing wrong?

Comment: remove quotient = 0 at the beginning

Comment: also return should be indented one more time

Comment: What do you understand from that error message? Also, is that a [mcve]? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0):

```
return quotient;
```

remove the semicolon

it should be like this:

```
return quotient
```